# JDBC MySQL does not read latest inserts

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have written a sample program to give an example of this problem, which causes an old resultset to return.

http://pastebin.com/QbyqUuRR **(UPDATE!)**

The workflow i'm doing is this:

- Doing a SELECT in an empty table
- INSERT one row
- SELECT again from that table (like the first SELECT) - **it gives me still zero rows**

My.cnf: http://pastebin.com/FVAjdUiM using Percona Server 5.5 (conf.d dir is empty)

ojacobson from freenode ##java helped me figure out, that this works with his environment, but mine actually doesn't.

What could cause the second select to fail?

When i reconnect to the server before the second SELECT, my test succeeds. it returns one row.

Comment: And just to be clear, you are making the insert and the select using the same connection?

Comment: yes, like in the code at pastebin. reconnecting does the trick

Comment: this sounds like a COMMIT problem

Comment: I just ran your code and it works just fine, I do not see any problems. Why did you conclude that the second select is not bringing any results?

Comment: @StefanN Do calls to `stmt.executeUpdate()` or `connection.commit();` throw exceptions? Also what is the return value of `stmt.executeUpdate()`?

Comment: edwin, because in my environment it really doesn't. crazy, right?! maybe some mysql config issue? and randy, as you see in the code sample, i did commit

Comment: @StefanN It is not evident in your code how you determined that the second query did not return any results. Can elaborate on that?

Comment: alain, no exceptions are thrown. `stmt.executeUpdate()` returns 1 row. edwin, have a look at the updated code, i added outputs to compare your results with mine.